# How do CSRF tokens protect from malicious GET followed by POST in another tab

Tags: csrf, csrf-protection

I know I am missing something, but please help me understand. Consider this situation:
I have a website called goodbank.com. URL http://goodbank.com/transfer/ serves a HTML page on GET with a form to transfer money to another account.  The form has a random token to prevent CSRF attack. On the server, token validity is checked on POST and the corresponding controller allows only authenticated sessions.

Let's say that in my browser, I login to  goodbank.com/. In another tab, I go to robgoodbank.com. As part of the served page, it has javascript to do AJAX request to goodbank.com/transfer/ to get a valid form. It then fills in other fields in the form and does a POST. My account is cleaned out :(

How does existing protection schemes protect against such an attack?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Unless your server allows [Cross Origin Resource Sharing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing), the browser will reject the `XMLHttpRequest`.  As per the link, the `XMLHttpRequest` sends the `Origin` header containing the domain from which the request originates. If the server does not respond with `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` containing a wildcard of that domain, the browser will reject the request.  There are actually a number of `Access-Control-` headers to control access including allowable methods, etc.

For extra protection, your server should check the `Origin` if it is present and the `Referer` HTTP header, which will be "http://robgoodbank.com" in your example, and you can also reject the request.

These are by no means foolproof, but do provide extra layers of protection.  There are mechanisms (such as extensions) to spoof the Referer, but those would have been employed by the user unless their browser has been compromised in some way. If their browser has been compromised they are in a lot more trouble...

Comment: Just to add to this, the important fixes here are the referrer and origin checks. Without those, it would be easy enough to perform the GET request in a hidden iframe to pull out any kind of anti-csrf token that can be used in the subsequent POST request.

Comment: But if cors is not allowed then even the post request would not succeed even without csrf protection right ?